# Google Sheet Formula / Appscript with Google Form Results

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating an automated Roster which takes Data via Google Forms.
The Goal of this is for the Data to go into the Sheet that Google Forms Makes automatically.

The issue I'm having is trying to get specific data from this to another Sheet in the same Spreadsheet.

I have a formula for automatically sorting the Rostered data so I need a way to take the specific data being entered and automatically put it in a Row.

I've tried an OnEdit LastRow solution but unfortunately that creates an entirely new Row which prevents any pre-existing Formulas.

TL;DR
Google Form Entries go into Sheet.
Need to move those Form Entries to another Sheet in the same Spreadsheet.
Cannot create an entirely new Row because it will prevent the Formula used for sorting from being used.

Comment: It is hard to imagine what you are trying to do only from this description, but I would try to use formulas before going to code. White formulas, simply use the =SORT() function to copy the data from the original range and present it in a sorted way.

Comment: I agree with Oren. While you can see your entire spreadsheet in front of you and know your end goal thoroughly, we here do not. I invite you to share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it) and then to be specific, using range references, about where and what the desired results should be.